# Не работает clip: в CSS и append() или prepend() в JS, почему?

Tags: javascript

На ноутбуке старом стоит Windows XP, Sublime Text соответствующий ОС, Хром такой же древний. На что грешить, если такая штука:
clip: rect(); в CSS файле глупит и не работает, плагины вроде все стоят свежие(Emmet и  всё такое...).
А в JS не срабатывают добавления prepend() и append(), а так же перебрать элементы через for of и for in нормально не получается.
Где косяк? Допустим:

```js
    for(let li of tree.querySelectorAll('li')){
        let span = document.createElement('span');
        span.classList.add('show');
        li.prepend(span);
        span.append(span.nextSibling);
    }
```

Консоль выдает ошибки и каждый раз разные, то то не определено, то другое.

Это список обычный, его фрагмент. Решил от лени добавить элементов с классами к li

```html
    <ul id="tree" class="tree">
      <li>Products
        <ul>
          <li>Product 1</li>
          <li>Product 2</li>
          <li>Product 3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

выдает: `Uncaught TypeError: tree.querySelectorAll(...)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function`

Пробовал перебирать и обычным циклом, с предварительным объявлением переменной вне цикла, но тогда ругается на prepend и append

Comment: Приложите код ошибок. Возможно просто версия браузера старая, не поддерживает

Comment: tree.querySelector('li') не может являться массивом

Comment: @МихаилКамахин по правде говоря querySelectorAll - тоже

Answer (score 1):

В коде нет ошибки. Проблема, собственно, в используемом старом браузере, `append()` доступен начиная с [54-й версии хрома](https://caniuse.com/?search=ParentNode%20API%3A%20append)

Можно заменить:

`elem.append(node)` → `elem.appendChild(node)`

`elem.prepend(node)` → `elem.insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", node)`

Ну и `for...of` на обычный цикл со счетчиком

```js
var li = tree.querySelectorAll('li');

for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.textContent = "Test ";
  span.classList.add('show');
  
  li[i].insertAdjacentElement("afterbegin", span);
  span.appendChild(span.nextSibling); 
}
```

```html
<ul id="tree" class="tree">
  <li>Products
    <ul>
      <li>Product 1</li>
      <li>Product 2</li>
      <li>Product 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Или использовать [полифиллы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append#polyfill).